# jQuery click on list item and change select option

Tags: jquery

I have select option drop down menu. 
The options are also stored in list and I want to change select option based on click event on the list item.

```
<select id="pa_sc30-glossy-colors" name="attribute_pa_sc30-glossy-colors" class="film">
    <option value="">Choose color…</option>
    <option class="active" id="440" value="440" hidden="hidden">---</option>
    <option class="active" id="30-23-stone-yellow" value="30-23-stone-yellow">30-23 Stone Yellow</option>
    <!-- other options... -->
</select>
```

```js
// All options are stored in array 'var arr []'
// Each value of the array is stored in the tag '<li>'
// tag '<li>' is added to the list <ul class = "choose_variations">

var arr = [];
var list = $('.choose_variations');

    // Store options in array
    $('.film option').each(function() {
        arr.push( $(this).text() );
    });

    // Append list items to ul.choose_variations
    $.each(arr, function(i) {
        $('<li>').text(arr[i]).appendTo(list);
    });


    // Remove '---' and 'Choose color' list items    
    $('.choose_variations li').filter(
    function() {
        if( $(this).text() == '---' || $(this).text() == 'Choose color…'){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });



// change select option if is clicked on list item

$('.choose_variations li').click(function() {
    $('.film option[text="' + $(this).text() + '"]').trigger("change"); 
});
```

here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbjaksq8/1/)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jbjaksq8/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should amend you array to store both the `text` and the `value` of the `option`:

```
var arr = $('.film option').map(function () {
    return { text: $(this).text(), value: $(this).val() };
});
```

Then on click of the links you can `select` the option from the `select` by its `value`:

```
$('.choose_variations li').click(function () {
    $('.film').val($(this).data('val'))
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jbjaksq8/2/)

Also note that if you `arr` variable is only used to build the list of `li` element you can combine your two `each()` loops:

```
$('.film option').each(arr, function() {
    $('<li>', { text: $(this).text(), value: $(this).val() }.appendTo(list);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i've user a data attribute to save the option value.

the solution

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbjaksq8/5/)

```
$('.film option').each(function() {
    arr.push( $(this).text() );
});
```

is not needed anymore i think.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dirty version that works:

Demo@[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/jbjaksq8/6/)

Code change:

```
list.on("click", "li", function() {
    $('.film').val( $.trim($(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, "-"))); 
});
```

Improvement:

Store the option value in the list item as a data attribute, something like:

```
<li data-opt-val="optionValueHere"></li>
```

And then:

```
list.on("click", "li", function() {
    $('.film').val( $(this).data("optVal") ); 
});
```